# How to store GPG keys in TPM

Tags: gnupg, tpm, code-signing

Am working on GPG mechanism to code sign my debian packages. I have generated both Master Key pair and Subordinate Key pairs to sign my packages. Now i want to store my key-pair in TPM hardware instead of Key ring. Later i want to delete my key ring and i want to retrieve keys from TPM.

Can anybody explain what is the mechanism to store and retrieve the code signing key securely in TPM, for secure code signing.

Comment: Usually the whole point of storing keys on a hardware token is that they **are not** retrievable... Are you using TPM 1.2 or TPM 2.0? They need completely different software.

Comment: Am using TPM2.0. I want to retrieve also whenever is needed

Comment: Then what's the point of using a TPM?

Comment: ok, lets forget about retrieving keys from TPM. Can you please explain me about how to store these keys in TPM?

Answer (score 2):

GPG, as of version 2.3, has native support for TPMs, see

[Using a TPM with GnuPG 2.3](https://gnupg.org/blog/20210315-using-tpm-with-gnupg-2.3.html)

This is handled in gpg-agent via an external program called `tpm2daemon`. On OpenSuse, the package to install is called `gpg2-tpm`. Ubuntu, as of Noble, ships with [GPG 2.4.4](https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/gpg)

Answer (score 1):

For GnuPG 2.x, you would need:

1. Either native TPM2 support in gpg's `scdaemon` program (the smartcard handler component),
2. or a replacement `scdaemon` program which uses TPM2,
3. or a replacement `scdaemon` program which uses PKCS#11 modules, and in turn a PKCS#11 module which uses TPM2.

Right now, options #1 and #2 aren't possible (the needed scdaemon replacement simply does not exist yet). Option #3 should be possible, using [gnupg-pkcs11-scd](https://github.com/alonbl/gnupg-pkcs11-scd) and [tpm2-pkcs11](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-pkcs11).

However, the latter project is still under heavy development and its usage might literally change in the coming weeks, so I can't really start writing instructions for it right now... I will probably return to this thread sometime later when tpm2-pkcs11 has settled down.

Comment: Using "GPG" and "tpm-tools" on TPM1.2 machine i created public keys, private keys. ALso i tried sealing and unsealing my private keys. I referred to below link "https://tonytruong.net/how-to-use-the-tpm-to-secure-your-iot-device-data/". Now can u tell me how to store my privatekey or keyblob in to tpm?

Comment: Sealing/unsealing isn't very useful – if you can simply unseal the private key, then the TPM doesn't give you very much at all. Normally keys would be either imported or directly generated _on_ the TPM, so that they would be non-exportable and all operations would happen within the TPM itself...

Comment: Because of that, there isn't really any good way to integrate sealing/unstealing via PKCS#11 or any similar method – nobody bothered to write such integration. It's entirely up to you to write e.g. a pam_exec script that unseals the files upon login.

Comment: (And unfortunately, even for the PKCS#11 method I described, you won't have much luck if you use TPMv1.2 – it needs a daemon called 'pkcsslotd' from OpenCryptoki, which seems to be a buggy mess. The tpm2-pkcs11 project for TPMv2.0 is a bit more stable already.)

Comment: Actually i tried on TPM2.0 first, but i didn't get much tpm2-tool options so switched back TPM1.2

Comment: Any news? Would be really interested in a working solution :-)

Comment: I looks like it is not possible, though this post makes it sound like it might not be a one-to-one with smartcards https://gnupg.org/blog/20210315-using-tpm-with-gnupg-2.3.html